# Pairing Heap - Implementation of Assignment Operator / Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, pairing-heap

I'm trying to implement a paring heap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), but I seem to be having trouble writing the assignment operator and copy constructor.  My default constructor as well as my push and pop functions seem to work. But when I try to make a new heap via copy construction or do an assignment I segfault either during the copy or on the first subsequent operation. I've included the relevant code segments from what I think are the problem below. If anyone could give me some advice on how to proceed it would be appreciated.

```
template<typename T>
PairingHeap<T>::PairingHeap(const PairingHeap& other) {
    length = 0;
    copy(other.root);
}

template<typename T>
PairingHeap<T>& PairingHeap<T>::operator=(const PairingHeap & rhs) {
    length = 0;
    if(root != rhs.root){
        destroy(root);
        copy(rhs.root);
    }

    return *this;
}


void destroy(Node* A){
    if( A != NULL ){
        destroy( A->child );
        destroy( A->sibling );
        delete A;
    }
}

void copy(Node* A){
    if(A == nullptr) return;
    else push(A->elt);

    if(A->child != nullptr) copy(A->child);
    if(A->sibling != nullptr) copy(A->sibling);
}


template<typename T>
typename PairingHeap<T>::Node* PairingHeap<T>::push(const T& val ) {
    length++;

    Node* node = new Node(val);
    if(root == NULL)
        root = node;
    else root = meld(root, node);
    return node;
}

Node* meld(Node* A, Node* B){
    if(B == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if(A->elt < B->elt){
        B->prev = A->prev;
        A->prev = B;
        A->sibling = B->child;
        if(A->sibling != nullptr)
            A->sibling->prev = A;
        B->child = A;
        A = B;
        return A;
    }
    else{
        B->prev = A;
        A->sibling = B->sibling;
        if(A->sibling != nullptr)
            A->sibling->prev = A;
        B->sibling = A->child;
        if(B->sibling != nullptr)
            B->sibling->prev = B;
        A->child = B;
        return A;
    }
}


template<typename T>
void PairingHeap<T>::pop() {
    Node *oldRoot = root;

    if(root->child == nullptr)
        root = nullptr;
    else
        root = merge(root->child);

    delete oldRoot;
    length--;
}


Node* merge(Node* A)
    std::vector<Node*> v;

    if(A == nullptr || A->sibling == nullptr)
       return A;

    for(int i = 0; A != nullptr; i++){
        v.push_back(A);
        A->prev->sibling = nullptr;
        A = A->sibling;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < (int)v.size(); i++){
        v[i] = meld(v[i-1],v[i]);
    }

   return v[v.size()-1];
}
```

Comment: If you run it in a debugger, where does it crash?  what is the stack trace?  Also, you should post a complete example that can reproduce the problem.  Also, there is no copy constructor listed in the code you have provided, so did you just mean the copy method?

Comment: Sorry, I must have forgotten the copy constructor, I'll edit it in now. I get a segfault on trying to pop() off or push() onto the pairing heap after using either assignment or copy constructor.

Comment: `destroy(root)` leaves `root` a dangling pointer (a non-NULL pointer whose pointee has been deleted). `addNode` probably doesn't handle this situation gracefully